# Title of Payment Method in Magento

Tags: magento

How can I get title of payment method in magento ? Also I have some related questions :

- How can I add payment method selected on review order page(I override the page but I dont know how to call present qoute's payment method. I have used

  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getData()

  But its just providing me payment method code not title
- How can I get payment method name by its code ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it by:

```php
$mcode = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
    ->getQuote()
    ->getPayment()
    ->getMethodInstance()
    ->getTitle();

echo Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/' . $mcode . '/title');
```

Answer (score 11):

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();`

To get a payment method by code:

`Mage::helper('payment')->getMethodInstance($payment_code);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

```php
$payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
$methods = array(array(
    'value'=>'',
    'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('--Please Select--')
));

foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) {
    $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
    $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
        'label'   => $paymentTitle,
        'value' => $paymentCode,
    );
}

echo "<xmp>";
print_r($methods);
echo "</xmp>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me for getting the actual payment method title using payment code:

`Mage::helper('payment')->getMethodInstance([payment_code])->getTitle();`

Ref: built off @Lucas Moeskops answer (+1'ed you)